# Python get variables from JSON: Unexpected errors

Tags: python, json, variables

Im trying to create a script that will read a JSON file and use the variables to select particular folders and files and save them somewhere else.

My JSON is as follows:

```
{
    "source_type": "folder",
    "tar_type": "gzip",
    "tar_max_age": "10",
    "source_include": {"/opt/myapp/config", "/opt/myapp/db, /opt/myapp/randomdata"}
    "target_type": "tar.gzip",
    "target_path": "/home/user/targetA"

}
```

So far, I have this Python Code:

```
import time
import os
import tarfile
import json
source_config = '/opt/myapp/config.JSON'
target_dir = '/home/user/targetA'

def main():
    with open('source_config', "r").decode('utf-8') as f:
        data = json.loads('source_config')
        for f in data["source_include", str]:
                full_dir = os.path.join(source, f)
                tar = tarfile.open(os.path.join(backup_dir, f+ '.tar.gzip'), 'w:gz')
                tar.add(full_dir)
                tar.close()

    for oldfile in os.listdir(backup_dir):
       if str(oldfile.time) < 20:
           print("int(oldfile.time)")
```

My traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Documents/myapp/test/point/test/Test2.py", line 16, in <module>
    with open('/opt/myapp/config.json', "r").decode('utf-8') as f:
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Presumably your input JSON does not use `{"/opt/myapp/config", "/opt/myapp/db, /opt/myapp/randomdata"}`, but `[...]` instead.

Comment: not sure I understand the question...

Comment: Your input JSON is not valid; a list of items uses square brackets, but your input uses `{...}` for a list instead, and is missing a comma at the end. That line should use `["/opt/myapp/config", "/opt/myapp/db, /opt/myapp/randomdata"],` to be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call `.decode()` directly on the file object. You'd normally do that on the read lines instead. For JSON, however, you *don't need to do this*. The `json` library handles this for you.

Use `json.load()` (no `s`) to load directly from the file object:

```
with open(source_config) as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Next, you need to address the `source_include` key with:

```
for entry in data["source_include"]:
    base_filename = os.path.basename(entry)
    tar = tarfile.open(os.path.join(backup_dir, base_filename + '.tar.gzip'), 'w:gz')
    tar.add(full_dir)
    tar.close()
```

Your JSON also needs to be fixed, so that your source_include is an array, rather than a dictionary:

```
{
    "source_type": "folder",
    "tar_type": "gzip",
    "tar_max_age": "10",
    "source_include": ["/opt/myapp/config", "/opt/myapp/db", "/opt/myapp/randomdata"],
    "target_type": "tar.gzip",
    "target_path": "/home/user/targetA"

}
```

Next, you loop over filenames with `os.listdir()`, which are strings (relative filenames with no path). Strings do not have a `.time` attribute, if you wanted to read out file timestamps you'll have to use [`os.stat()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat) calls instead:

```
for filename in os.listdir(backup_dir):
    path = os.path.join(backup_dir, filename)
    stats = os.stat(path)
    if stats.st_mtime < time.time() - 20:
        # file was modified less than 20 seconds ago
```

Comment: Maybe change the variable name `f` in the loop so it's not the same as the file object?

Comment: That changes the traceback to:

with open('source_config') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'source_config'

Comment: @Brendan see the `with` line, I removed the quotes so it uses the string in the variable `source_config` rather than the string "source_config" which doesn't exist as a file.

Comment: No problem, also added extra info regarding the json (instead of writing another answer).

Comment: @JoshSmeaton: I made that a comment on the post itself, but sure.

Comment: Okay, that seems to resolve the issues.. since console generates no error. However, now theres absolutely no output, as in the *.tar.gz's arent generated and theres no reason why.. Cant post the revised script cos theres not enough chars available in the comment block :(

Comment: @Brendan: Your `entry` filenames are full paths, with a `/` at the start. I've adjusted the code a little to take *just* the last part, because with a starting slash `os.path.join()` will *ignore* any items before a path starting with a slash. Your backup files are created in `/opt/myapp/config.tar.gzip`, etc. otherwise.

Comment: I Understand the logic, I just dont understand why it refuses to output.. I removed the /, but still absolutely no output...

Comment: Perhaps create a new question with some more detail then; you initial problems have been solved here. Stack Overflow is not a debugging service, really, though. I'd add a few `print` statements to see what paths are being generated, use `os.isfile()` to test if you are really looking at actual files, etc.

Comment: Your answer, if I could, would DEFINATELY be upvoted. A LOT. Thanks for ALL the help sir, most appreciated!